# G++ Compiles, but nothing happens

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I am currently running `g++` version `4.3.4` and when I run the following command:

> g++ -g -Wall test.cpp -o test.exe

on this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
   cout << "Hello World!";
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Nothing seems to happen: `Cygwin` seems to lag for a moment, but no `exe` is created (if there are errors in the `cpp` source, they are displayed)

And ideas?

Comment: what's the evidence that there is not file test.exe? did you search for it or just type 'test'? Depending on your path settings, the latter may call another 'test' ... Never use the name "test" for your executables!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're actually invoking the built in `test` command. Are you executing your program as `./test` or `./test.exe`? This should work, but I'd rename it, just in case.